# Processing lists of key-value pairs

Tags: vb.net, tuples, key-value

I have a list `inputList` of key value pairs like

```
X,10
X,30
Y,10
```

I want process them into a new list of key-value pairs formatted like "key component from initial list, sum of initial list values for keys that contain that key"
E.g.

```
X,40
Y,10
```

Would this approach work? I don't know the actual methods to use. Also, I don't think I can change the value of an existing key value pair, so I might have to delete the existing key from the output list and add a new one with the summed values.

```
For each inputPair in inputList
    If outputList.Contains(pair with Key = inputPair.Key)
        outputList.Item(Key = inputPair.Key).value = (inputPair.value + outputList.Item(Key = inputPair.Key).value)
    Else
        outputList.Add(New pair = inputPair.Key, inputPair.Value)
```

I'm open to using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ will probably be the simplest method if you can return a new List of KeyValuePairs rather than updating the existing one:

```
Dim result = _
    (From kvp In inputList
    Group kvp By kvp.Key Into Group
    Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)( _
        Key, Group.Sum(Function(kvp) kvp.Value))).ToList()
```

Assuming `inputList` is of type `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))`, this will return a new object `result` of the same type with summed results by key.